# Session destroy not working in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, salesforce, omniauth

I have used [omniauth-salesforce](https://github.com/realdoug/omniauth-salesforce) in my sessions controller I have following code, even when I logout the session is still present, I have tried `session.clear` and `reset_session` in destroy method but nothing works, sign in works only after clearing browser cache

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

How to delete session on signout?

Comment: Hello M.R how did you solve this issue? I'm using omniauth Facebook and twitter gems and ended up with the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Session is similar to a normal hash so below thing should work.

```
session.delete(:user_id)
```

Comment: I added above in sessions controller destroy method but still not working

Comment: Means it didn't delete user_id from session you are saying ?

Comment: When I puts session[:user_id] at the beginning of destroy method it returns 1 after this code (session[:user_id] = nil), the value set to nil

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 session[:user_id] = nil if session[:user_id]
```